# Trying to remove a shelf in a corner cabinet to install a lazy susan, can't figure out how to remove shelf!

Tags: installation, shelf

I'm installing a Rev A Shelf lazy susan but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the shelf out short of cutting it in 1/2. I'm wondering if it was put in the cabinet before the countertop was installed. I've tried twisting it every way I can figure, but I'm stumped at this point. Maybe a circular saw is the answer ‍♂️

[image]

Comment: Can you lift the back of the shelf at all? (The corner part.)  Or the front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get that shelf out without cutting it in half. There is no way to tilt it out.

I used to build these lazy susan corner cabinets. The only way to get the shelf into the cabinet was to put it in before the cabinet was fully assembled, thus sealing it in.

If you think you may remove the lazy susan one day and can live with the shelf thickness' loss of height, you could screw down the shelf in the far corners so the screws aren't easily visible, then pretend the shelf is the bottom of the cabinet and attach the lazy susan hardware to it. On removal of the lazy susan hardware, you can unscrew the shelf from the bottom and restore the shelf to proper usage. Or screw the shelf to the top of the cabinet and pretend the shelf is the top for attaching the lazy susan. Putting the shelf up top would hide the lazy susan mounting holes if the shelf is returned to service later.

Otherwise, chop away. It's the only way. A jigsaw may be safer than a circular saw.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm preparing to do. I'll lose a little over 1/2" of vertical space, but no big deal. I'm just going to put a secret message in between the shelf and the bottom of the cabinet for some future DIYer to find lol. Thanks!

Comment: Collect a full set of 2023 coins and tuck those in with the message. You can drill shallow holes in the way-back if the thickness of the coins feels like too much to lose...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from a picture, but either you can stand  it up under the countertop near-enough vertical to slide out, or you can't. Basically slide and pull the end near one side up the side until the edge touches the countertop underside. If it won't turn and slide out the door at that angle, probably it's saw-time.

Comment: Closest I can get to vertical is 45 degrees. Believe me, I've tried every which way! I may just put it in the bottom of the cabinet and install the lazy susan on top of it instead of destroying an expensive piece of cabinetry! Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.